# Dissolving shapefile python script not working, syntax help please

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, dissolve

I do not understand why this simple script won't work. I can get it to dissolve in model builder but not from a script that I run from inside the map document. My output results are 4 polygons, just like my input file. I only want one.

Any suggestions?

```py
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Local variables:
env.workspace="C:\\Test\\shapefiles"

infeatures = "Multipolys.shp"
outfeatures = "C:\\Test\\shapefiles\\Dissolve.shp"

# Process: Dissolve
arcpy.Dissolve_management(infeatures, outfeatures, "", "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

correct syntax is:

```py
arcpy.Dissolve_management(infeatures, outfeatures, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

ArcGIS 10.1 advanced.

Answer (score 4):

The [syntax](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) is

```py
Dissolve_management (in_features, out_feature_class, {dissolve_field}, {statistics_fields}, {multi_part}, {unsplit_lines})
```

You need to specify the dissolve_field as the third parameter - here you've left it blank.

Comment: I intentionally left it blank (it is optional) as I do not want to dissolved on a field. I want it one polygon. Dissolving it on a field will not do this. Coordinates are the same, ran repair. Might need to run in 'foreground'. How would I do this?

Comment: Duh. Syntax is 'arcpy.Dissolve_management(infeatures, outfeatures, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")' Still need to figure out how to run in foreground though.